# python string comparision using tesseract and opencv

Tags: python, string, opencv, tesseract

The call to below with an image gives me correct result.
However string equality fails for unknown reason.

```
def image_to_string(im, cleanup = cleanup_scratch_flag):
    """Converts im to file, applies tesseract, and fetches resulting text.
    If cleanup=True, delete scratch files after operation."""
    try:
        util.image_to_scratch(im, scratch_image_name)
        call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
        text = util.retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root)
    finally:
        if cleanup:
            util.perform_cleanup(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
    return text


cityname=image_to_string(im)
print cityname # this statement prints 'London' without quotes
print cityname=='London' # This statement is always false
```

Answer (score 2):

To see what's happening, try doing `print repr(cityname)` and `print type(cityname)`.

Also try `print str(cityname) == 'London'`; it should result in a `True`.

Most likely `cityname` is *not* a string but some other, OpenCV-specific object type. It likely has its `str()` method return the recognized string value; this is what `print` prints.

Comment: That tip helped.There are some additional newline sequences

Answer (score 0):

```
print cityname
print repr(cityname) 
print type(cityname)
print str(cityname) == 'LONDON'
```

## Output

```
LONDON
'LONDON\n\n'
<type 'str'>
False

print cityname.rstrip() # is returning true
```